# MEF - Change default creation policy to NonShared

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, mef

I'm currently working on using MEF to scan/compose extensions to my applications. I'd like to change the default creation policy to non-shared (in lieu of shared), but have it so that the creation policy is override-able via attributes. In other words, if I don't specify a creation policy on the export, I want MEF to use non-shared.

My previous implementation isn't working for me anymore because that changes the required creation policy for all imports. So if I override the creation policy, the export doesn't get composed.

I've searched around and the closest I could get is the new RegisrationBuilder, but I'm working with .NET 4 (so MEF 1) in VS2010. I also couldn't figure out a way with ExportProviders.

Any help is greatly appreciated; thanks in advance!

Comment: I haven't tried the TransientCompositionContainer yet but it looks like it changes the CreationPolicy.Any (default) to CreationPolicy.NonShared. Hence the imports with explicit CreationPolicy.Shared should still work and everything else should be transient.

Comment: Another approach (though I have never tried it) would be to create a custom import attribute (this should be similar to the custom export attribute guidelines http://mef.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Exports%20and%20Metadata) with a RequiredCreationPolicy set to NonShared by default. Then update all imports with this attribute. Apparetnly this is not as elegant as the TransientCompositionContainer.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to create a [MEF wrapper](https://github.com/mnikolovski/Emit.ExtensibilityProvider/) that I am using as an app bootstrap.
In the projects where I use MEF i have mu custom attributes which i use to controle toe instancing mode.
Custom implementation of an attribute would be:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Parameter, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = false)]
public class BusinessLogicImportAttribute : ConstraintImportAttribute
{
    public BusinessLogicImportAttribute()
        : base(typeof(IBusinessController))
    {
        base.RequiredCreationPolicy = RequiredCreationPolicy = CreationPolicy.NonShared;
    }
}
```